# Nerddinner inserting longitude and latitude to database MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, geolocation, bing-maps, latitude-longitude, nerddinner

i am facing a problem in the nerddinner, what i am facing:

in the DinnerForm.ascx there is a javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        NerdDinner.EnableMapMouseClickCallback();

        $("#Dinner_Address").blur(function (evt) {
            //If it's time to look for an address, 
            // clear out the Lat and Lon
            $("#Dinner_Latitude").val("0");
           $("#Dinner_Longitude").val("0");
            var address = jQuery.trim($("#Dinner_Address").val());
            if (address.length < 1)
                return;
            NerdDinner.FindAddressOnMap(address);
        });
    });
```

when i run the project, and i insert new Dinner, the longitude and the latitude inserted with value 0;

and when i changed the "0" to any number

$(document).ready(function () {
        NerdDinner.EnableMapMouseClickCallback();

```
    $("#Dinner_Address").blur(function (evt) {
        //If it's time to look for an address, 
        // clear out the Lat and Lon
        $("#Dinner_Latitude").val("12");//
       $("#Dinner_Longitude").val("12");//
        var address = jQuery.trim($("#Dinner_Address").val());
        if (address.length < 1)
            return;
        NerdDinner.FindAddressOnMap(address);
    });
});
```

it inserts the value 12 for both long and lat to the database

so i knew its inserting this value to the database, but am not sure actually

so i really want to know how i can fix this, plz any one :D

Comment: What is it that you want it to do?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing, when I insert a dinner, the location displays correctly in the create (and edit) page, but in the details page it uses the 0,0 location.

Answer (score 1):

Look in **Scripts/NerdDinner.js** for this block of code:

```
//If we've found exactly one place, that's our address.
//lat/long precision was getting lost here with toLocaleString, changed to toString
if (NerdDinner._points.length === 1) {
    $("#Latitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Latitude.toString());
    $("#Longitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Longitude.toString());
}
```

The problem appears to be that this script tries to set the values for elements named **Latitude** and **Longitude**, but in **Views\Dinners\DinnerForm.ascx**, those element ids are resolved as **Dinner_Latitude** and **Dinner_Longitude**, respectively.  As a workaround, you should be able modify two lines in **NerdDinner.js** so it would update either element it finds:

```
if (NerdDinner._points.length === 1) {
    $("#Latitude,#Dinner_Latitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Latitude.toString());
    $("#Longitude,#Dinner_Longitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Longitude.toString());
}
```

Comment: +1! I my case this solved the problem that given an address the map wouldn't find it and center to that address. Thank you!

Comment: @John Thanks, glad to know it helped someone!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that *none* of the values in the edit page were persisted.  It was an issue in DinnersController.cs.

I changed

```
UpdateModel(dinner, "Dinner");
```

to

```
UpdateModel(dinner);
```

It seemed that the problem was that the controller code was expecting keys named Dinner.Id, Dinner.Title, etc. but the keys were actually named just Id and Title (etc.).